# JavaFX: How to get width of label before displaying?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, label

In my JavaFX application, the user logs in and the application retrieves data about the user.  One piece of data is their company name.  The application must adjust the text to maintain width of the `Label`.

I have a `textProperty()` listener which adjusts the font size of a `TextField` within a `Label`.  The width functionality works.  Regardless of the length of the company name, it fits.  However, the smaller text squishes up closer to the y coordinate of the `Label` like so:

[image]
[image]
*Bordered for emphasis.  The top is what it looks like when it fits into the width.  The bottom resizes the font correctly, but doesn't adjust the y coordinate accordingly.*

So, I have two ideas, and I do not know how to do either.

- Find a way to have the `setLayoutY()` set the vertical center of the `Label`, rather than the top of the `Label`, to maintain vertical centering regardless of size.
- Use `setLayoutY()` to adjust the y coordinate of the `Label` based on the new font size.  The issue here is that I do not know how to get the width of my text *before* I display it, so in my code below, `labelHeight` is the same `labelHeight` as with the default font as it has not applied yet.

```java
// Resizes text to fit name lengths
companyNameLabel.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

    Text tmpText = new Text(newValue);
    tmpText.setFont(Font.font("Oxygen", 72));

    double textWidth = tmpText.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();

    // Check if text width is greater than maximum width
    if (textWidth > 470) {

        // Change font size to fit within 470
        double newFontSize = 72 * 470 / textWidth;
        companyNameLabel.setFont(Font.font("Oxygen", newFontSize));

        // Finds y value for vertical centering
        double labelHeight = companyNameLabel.getHeight();
        System.out.println(labelHeight);
        companyNameLabel.setLayoutY(155 - labelHeight / 2);

    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong, but with a `Text` node you can add it to an invisible dummy Pane first to get the width. After that, you can do what you need to do.

Comment: Here is something you can look into. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/text/TextBoundsType.html

Comment: The link you posted seems like it is what I want, but I'm having trouble understanding it.  It actually has a `public static final TextBoundsType LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER` which, "is typically used to center Text nodes vertically within the bounds of its parent."  However, I'm not sure how I use this.  It doesn't really give examples.  I'm unsure as to how I set the constant and how I apply it to a `Label` (or `Text`).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anybody else made the same mistake.  I had tried changing the positioning to `CENTER_LEFT` before, but it did not work for me, because I had my height set to automatically compute the height.  If you have a set height, this will work fine.  I've concluded that I must be braindead.